# Bot Emulator V4 connection: request to https://localhost:44378/api/messages failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, botframework

In the latest Bot Framework Emulator 4.0.0-preview.40025 (although it this has occurred in every version I try), I get the following error:

```
[11:37:11]Emulator listening on http://localhost:65141
[11:37:11]ngrok not configured (only needed when connecting to remotely hosted bots)
[11:37:11]Connecting to bots hosted remotely
[11:37:11]Edit ngrok settings
[11:37:11]POST201directline.startConversation
[11:37:11]request to https://localhost:44378/api/messages failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
[11:37:11]request to https://localhost:44378/api/messages failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

The original V3 Bot framework emulator works fine.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? running into the same problem

Comment: Sort of. My understanding was v4 bots only worked under HTTPS. So i had set my IISExpress settings to use HTTPS and was getting the problem I reported. Turned out my assumption was false, and you can run/debug under HTTP. So the problem went away as my debug sessions were HTTP and not HTTPS.